# Developer Transitioning to Drupal/Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, drupal-7, drupal-8

For the past 3 years I have been a PHP developer writing and creating websites in a "Vanilla" fashion (no CMS). When I created or altered a site I would write my own html, php, css and js files. I just started a job this week as a web developer at a small company that exclusively uses Drupal7/8 and Wordpress.

I was assigned, what in my mind is a simple task, of creating a landing page with a carousel and a form on it. In my past vanilla life this would take me all of two hours to have it live. This site however was created in Drupal 7 by a developer no longer at the company.

I have been through both Lynda.com courses on Drupal 7&8 development and have a good grasp on the concepts, but still don't know where to even begin.

Is there anyone out there who has come from a similar background of web development outside of a CMS and has since moved into it that can give me some advice on where to begin?

Thanks!

I followed the step in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WsLA7n9fknc
and here was the output I got on the page:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXiHO.jpg)

Comment: Hi Mike, it may help by posting what you're trying to achieve specifically. Code examples, screenshots, what you've tried could really help us help you.

Comment: Thanks for the comment WPZA, I have updated the question with what I have attempted so far.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to install and use drupal contrib modules to create the carousel and the form, for example:

- Create a view with Views Slideshow module, you could start following this example:

https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/modules/views-slideshow/creating-a-slideshow

- Use the webform module to create a simple form, please see the following tutorial: https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/webform-module